# How to prevent toast message when creatin app icon on screen

Tags: android, icons, toast

I want to create **appp icon** on phone screen and i do it but when i do it **automaticli app creates toast message**, How to prevent this toast message when creatin app icon or deleting icon on screen?
Thanks.

[image]

**That is code of how i do it**

```
private void addShortcut(){
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

// Shortcut name
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), "."+this.getLocalClassName());
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

// Shortcut icon
ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);

sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
}


private void delShortcut(){
Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

// Shortcut adı
shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));

String appClass = this.getPackageName() + "." +this.getLocalClassName();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), appClass);
shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
delShortcut();
addShortcut();
```

**Permissions for adding shortcuts**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: whats wrong with it?, if something giving you information.

Comment: it every time when client opens the app app shows this message, its not commfortable for client

Comment: Side-note: You shouldn't be adding stuff to people's home screens if they don't want it there.

Comment: User can see all allowed premission when downloads app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create hidden properties (i create CheckBox), after create shortcut set this true, then check parameter:

```
private void checkShortcut() {
        shortCut = GlobalClass.PREFS.getBoolean("ShortCut", false);
        if (shortCut == true) {
            //addShortcut();
        }
        else{
            remShortcut();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ValehAğayev Can you please post the whole code, where should i be putting the above piece of code?

Comment: Can you provide more explanation of how this works and should be used pleased?  I would like to create shortcuts without a toast and this is the only post with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, there is no way to prevent a default system `Toast` from appearing.

Comment: But in some application i saw that it creates icon and not shows the toast message. I think it possible

Comment: Dianne Hackborn works for Google's Android team, and [says it's not possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Y6rhIXTMr8M).